# Decompiled memcpy - what is the point of these instructions?

Tags: assembly

The memcpy function checks to see if the bytes to copy are less than 4.  If it is, then it uses a loop with

```
move byte ptr ds:[edi], al
```

To copy memory

However, if its not it uses these following instructions:

```
neg ecx
and ecx, 3
```

I understand that it's checking to see if 0 - ecx is divisible by 4.  But my question is this:

Why is neg ecx necessary?

```
edit:
    edx = bytes to copy
    ecx = address
    test edx, edx
    je exit
    xor eax, eax
    mov al, byte_to_copy
    push edi
    mov edi, ecx
    cmp edx, 4
    jb byte_by_byte_copy
    neg ecx
    and ecx, 3
    jnz byte_by_byte_copy
    mov ecx, eax
    shl eax, 8
    add eax, ecx
    mov ecx, eax
    shl eax, 10
    add eax, ecx
    mov ecx, edx
    and edx, 3
    shr ecx, 2
    je byte_by_byte_copy
    rep stos dword [edi]
    test edx, edx
    je exit
    (byte by byte routine copy here)
```

Comment: You need to provide more code.

Comment: what compiler and optimizations are you using? Most modern compilers will use much faster SSE/AVX operations, not `rep stos` like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they're doing is essentially a cheap computation of 3-(x modulo 4)

```
x      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
result 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 ...
```

and so on. As to why they're obtaining this value... now that you've provided code... I believe what they're doing is checking the address's data alignment before copying by words, but I'd need to dig into it more deeply to convince myself of that.

Comment: That's most certainly the reason. Copying dwords (or even qwords), is a lot faster if done on the correct boundaries.